# Extracting Regression Coefficients and using them for another dataset in R

Tags: r, regression

Suppose that I fit a standard linear model predicting y using x1,x2,..xn that has a lot of two and possibly three-way interactions. Then I have a separate dataset that has x1,x2,...xn, and want to create f(y). Is there a straight forward and easy way to do that which doesn't involve defining every interaction by hand in R?

Comment: Are you looking to `predict` onto this new dataset (then use `predict(model,newdata = ..)`.

Answer (score 3):

mnel is correct.

---

```
dat<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(30), 10, 3))

names(dat)<-c("y", "x1", "x2")

ans<-lm(y~x1*x2,dat)

summary(ans) # note three parameters + one intercept

predict(ans, newdata=list(x1=0,x2=0))  #only need x1 and x2 for newdata, not interaction
```

---

Newdata can contain as many entries as you want. The result will be expected outcome for new data given all parameters of the previously fitted model, including the interaction(s).